# In Pandas, extract unique values from a columns and display the results in a column

Tags: pandas

In pandas, I need to extract unique values from a column and display them as a column.

Here is my data:

```
Year,State,City,Month,Revenue,Cost
2012,FL,MI,1,10,5
2012,FL,MI,2,20,10
2012,FL,MI,2,20,5
2012,FL,MI,3,30,10
2012,FL,TA,1,10,5
2012,FL,TA,2,20,10
2012,GA,AT,1,10,5
2012,GA,AT,2,20,10
2012,GA,CO,1,10,5
2012,GA,CO,2,20,10
2013,FL,MI,1,10,5
2013,FL,MI,2,20,10
2013,FL,MI,2,20,5
2013,FL,TA,1,10,10
2013,FL,TA,2,20,5
2013,GA,AT,1,10,10
2013,GA,AT,2,20,5
2013,GA,CO,1,10,10
2013,GA,CO,2,20,5
```

I need to extract the unique names of each state, and then display them like this:

```
State
AL
FL
GA
```

I have tried various methods in Pandas. It seems that `pivot_table` likes to change the format of the data.  Usually I get reduced to a list this:

```
['FL' 'GA']
```

I suppose I could call unique on the `City` column. The issue comes into play when I want to see more than one column in this format. Take `State, City.`

The output would be:

```
FL, MI,
FL, TA,
GA, AT
...
```

So it ends up being a `groupby` but that gives some odd output if I am not looking for a value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you tried. Also, there is no AL in your sample dataset

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list you get from the [pandas.unique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) to a dataframe with [pandas.DataFrame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

res = pd.DataFrame(df.State.unique(), columns=['State'])

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
unique_df = df[['state','city']].drop_duplicates()
```